# Creating a number of matrices/vectors based on a number

Tags: matlab

I have a simple for loop that is used to simulated data,

```
for t=2:T;
        Y_star(t,1,b)=[Y_star(t-1,1,b) X_1_star(t-1,1,b) X_2_star(t-1,1,b) 1]*beta(:,i)+w(t-1)*e(t-1,i);
        X_1_star(t,1,b)=Theta(1,1)+Phi(1,:,1)*[X_1_star(t-1,1,b) ; X_2_star(t-1,1,b)]+w(t-1)*v(t-1,1,i);
        X_2_star(t,1,b)=Theta(2,1)+Phi(2,:,1)*[X_1_star(t-1,1,b) ; X_2_star(t-1,1,b)]+w(t-1)*v(t-1,2,i);
end;
```

The issue I am having is this is fine when I have two X variables, however, I would like to write the code so that I can increase the number of variables to change each time, 4 say.

In this case, I would need X_1_star, X_2_star, X_3_star and X_4_star.

I can handle the Phi and Theta coefficients, as well as the w and v and e however I am struggling with creating the matrices for X's.

### Any ideas would be greatly, I have tried storing the matrices within cells but I struggled to get this working.

Following the commnets, here is a simple example

%% Simple example 
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------%

```
Phi = [0.9954    0.0195;
       0.0012    0.9567];  
Theta= [0.007;0.051];
beta = [0.06;-0.10;1.66;-0.88];
N = 1;      
e = rand(370,1);
v = randn(370,2);
t = 371;
T = 371;
yy = rand(370,1);
X_1 = rand(370,1);
X_2 = rand(370,1);
B=50;
Y_star=zeros(T,N,B);
X_1_star=zeros(T,N,B);
X_2_star=zeros(T,N,B);
for b=1:B;
    Y_star(1,:,b)=yy(1,:);
    X_1_star(1,:,b)=X_1(1,:);
    X_2_star(1,:,b)=X_2(1,:);
    w=randn(T-1,1);
    for t=2:T;
        for i=1:N;
            Y_star(t,i,b)=[Y_star(t-1,i,b) X_1_star(t-1,i,b) ...
                X_2_star(t-1,i,b) 1]*beta(:,i)+w(t-1)*e(t-1,i);
            X_1_star(t,i,b)=Theta(1,i)+Phi(1,:,i)*[X_1_star(t-1,i,b) ; ...
                X_2_star(t-1,i,b)]+w(t-1)*v(t-1,1,i);
            X_2_star(t,i,b)=Theta(2,i)+Phi(2,:,i)*[X_1_star(t-1,i,b) ; ...
                X_2_star(t-1,i,b)]+w(t-1)*v(t-1,2,i);
        end;
    end;
    disp(b);
end;
```

I ideally this to do the same thing but not be dependent upon writing X_1 and X_2, as I would like to increase this sometimes to a larger number.

I have tried reshaping as the commnets suggested but not sure how this would or could work in this example.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I generally find structure arrays more useful for this kind of dynamic indexing (where you don't know how many you'll have of X_1_star, X_2_star...)

I didn't try to reproduce the whole example, but it might go something like this if you're trying to get up to X_4_star:

```
...
nX=4;
for i=1:N
    Y_star(t,i,b)=[Y_star(t-1,i,b) X_1_star(t-1,i,b) ...
                X_2_star(t-1,i,b) 1]*beta(:,i)+w(t-1)*e(t-1,i);
    for n=1:nX
        X(n).star(t,i,b)=...
    end
end
```

Comment: should this be a comment? I don't see a great deal of usefulness for the OP in order to find a working solution. Generally, answers will answer the question and comments give hits as you do?

Comment: @glacierbliss I appreciate the advice, I am also struggling to see how this could work. All of the X's need to be in Y_star and by themselves as shown in the example.

Comment: Further clarification if you have a viable idea would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @TonyChivers I provided a possible avenue to a solution to the original question. You took a dump on my effort to be helpful and reduced the chances that I'll try to be helpful on this site again.

Comment: @user30609 Good luck with the problem. I've had enough for today.

Comment: @glacierbliss I apologise on behalf of other users if any offence has been taken. Your solution at least promoted discussion and may have motivated another answer such as the one provided by TonyChivers. I am sure on behalf of all users of the site we appreciate any attempt to answer any question, this is the same for TonyChivers.

Comment: @glacierbliss as the OP mentioned, no offense meant and your solution did help me think of a way. All the best T

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is simply one of matrix algebra.

With the X variables it appears like you are simulating a small VAR model.

Instead of dynamic matrices as the answer above, I think it would make more sense to  simulating the x data as a larger matrix instead of vectors.

Here is a simple example,

First, I show you a two variable case, both in the method you use, and by jointly simulating the data...

Then I show with a 3 variable case how to extend this...

All you have to do is take the size of the beta matrix (or alpha) as I guessing these are determined before the matrix...

```
%Simulating a small VAR model 
%% 2 - variable case 
rng('default')
b = [0.4 0.5;0.6 0.07];  
a = [0.1 0.2];
v=randn(100,2);
x1 = zeros(100,1);
x2 = zeros(100,1);
xm=zeros(100,2);

T=100;
for t=2:T;
    x1(t)=a(1)+b(1,:)*[x1(t-1) ; x2(t-1)]+v(t-1,1); 
    x2(t)=a(2)+b(2,:)*[x1(t-1) ; x2(t-1)]+v(t-1,2);
end;

for t=2:T;
    xm(t,:)=a+xm(t-1,:)*b'+v(t-1,:)
end;

[xm x1 x2]

%% 3 - variable case 

rng('default')
b = [0.4 0.5 0.1;0.6 0.07 0.1; 0.3 0.4 0.7];  
a = [0.1 0.2 0.3];
v=randn(100,size(b,2));
xm=zeros(100,size(b,2));
for t=2:T;
    xm(t,:)=a+xm(t-1,:)*b'+v(t-1,:)
end;
```